# Small typesafe assertion library, is()

Tags: programming-challenge, typescript, generics

I need to write a function with the following requirements (Programming TypeScript book by B. Cherny, Chapter 4, exercise 5):

> Implement a small typesafe assertion library, `is`. Start by sketching out your types. When you’re done, you should be able to use it like this:
>
> ```
> // Compare a string and a string
> is('string', 'otherstring') // false
>
> // Compare a boolean and a boolean
> is(true, false) // false
>
> // Compare a number and a number
> is(42, 42) // true
>
> // Comparing two different types should give a compile-time error
> is(10, 'foo') // Error TS2345: Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>
> // [Hard] I should be able to pass any number of arguments
> is([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]) // false
> ```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
type AllowedTypes = string | boolean | number;

type Checker = {
  <T extends AllowedTypes>(l: T, r: T): boolean;
};

let is: Checker = <T>(l: T, r: T): boolean => {
  return l === r;
};

console.log(is('string', 'otherstring'));
console.log(is(true, false));
console.log(is(42, 42));
// console.log(is(10, 'foo')); // gives error
// console.log(is([1], [1])); // array not allowed
// console.log(is(1, [1])); // array not allowed

type MultiChecker = {
  <T>(...args: T[]): boolean;
};

let multi_is: MultiChecker = <T>(...args: T[]): boolean => {
  return args.every((v: T) => v === args[0]);
};

console.log(multi_is([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]));
console.log(multi_is(1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
console.log(multi_is('abcd', 'str', 'str'));
```

Please review it/suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t implemented one function, you’ve implemented two.

Your `multi_is()` function can handle any number of arguments, including 2, so it seems to me you could ditch the `is()` method and rename `multi_is()` to `is()`

Except, `multi_is()` can accept **any** number of arguments, including 0 & 1, which is probably not what is expected.

If the function was written with this signature:

```
let is: Checker = <T>(l: T, r: T, ...args: T[]): boolean => {
    ...
};
```

less than 2 arguments would be a compile-time error.

Comment: thanks for your comments. i deleted the is() function and renamed multi_is() to is(). but now there's one problem. the is() function shouldn't accept arrays, but now since multi_is() can accept arrays, is() does too. namely, this case: `is([1], [1])` how can i fix this?

Comment: I’m not certain it isn’t support to support `is([1], [1])`.  After all, it is suppose to return `False` for `is([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3])`, so it obviously should accept arrays.  In doesn’t say so in the problem description, but it isn’t a stretch to assume `is([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2])` should return `True`, and if so, `is([1, 2], [1, 2])` shouldn’t be rejected as a compile-time type error.

Comment: that's actually true, i just thought from problem statement examples that only `string | boolean | number` are allowed that's why i wrote it but i maybe it wasn't necessary.